# Find $a+b+c$ when $4abc=(a+3)(b+3)(c+3)$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, cubics

The Question is:-

> ***Given that $a,b,c \geq 4$
>   where $a,b,c$ belongs to integers
>   $$4abc=(a+3)(b+3)(c+3)$$
>   Find the value of $(a+b+c).$***

This  question is from an olympiad-PRMO ,the question though have solutions but none is so satisfying they simply make some assumptions here and there just to get the right answer (so I would not be revealing the answer).

I also tried the question by simply just simplifying the equation but i failed to narrow down to a result

I would like to see a nice,elegant and simple solution without any assumptions...

Comment: See [here](https://www.quora.com/If-a-3-b-3-c-3-4abc-then-what-is-the-value-of-a-b-c).

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ integers?

Comment: For integers it is solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888377/finding-value-of-a-bc

Comment: Without integer values, there are infinitely many possible values for $a+b+c$

Comment: Yes i just edited that